# Trying to instantiate a UIView through class method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview

I'm experimenting with different ways of displaying a `UIView` on the screen... I currently have this code, and think it should work to add a green `UIView` to the app's window, however, it doesn't:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        NSLog(@"init");
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        self.alpha = 1;
    }
    return self;
}

+ (SMLoginView *)sharedView{
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    static SMLoginView *sharedView;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedView = [[self alloc]initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
    });

    return sharedView;
}

+ (void)showLoginView{
    [[self sharedView]show];
}


- (void)show{
    NSLog(@"Show");
    [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] addSubview:self];
}
```

Comment: what is calling showLoginView?

Answer (score 1):

Insted, u can add it in the called method, because u are adding it in the shared class itself, thats wy it did't appeared.
try this

suppose u are calling this shared method in this "ViewController.m" class

```
   - (void)viewDidLoad
     {
         [super viewDidLoad];
     // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

         SMLoginView *sharedView =  [SMLoginView sharedView]; //you always get a shared view handle that view in this class 

         [self.view addSubview:sharedView]; //add the shared view hear not in the shared class.

    }
```

hope u got this :)